# Find the string permutation that has the most substring palidromes

Tags: java, python, c++, algorithm, sorting

For my Algorithms class, I have the following assignment; This was a Sorting homework, so I suspect I have to use some kind of sorting algorithm.

> Find string permutation that has the most substring palindromes. Input data is `N` (the length of string) and string `s` (`1 < N < 2000`). Output data should be a string that has the most palindromic substrings. (If there is more that contain the same amount, print anyone).

I have tried finding all permutations and then finding the permutation with most palindromic substrings, but there is a time limit of 1s and this way I overshoot that limit. Can anybody please help me with this task?

This is an input example:

INPUT:

```
5
abccb
```

OUTPUT:

```
bcacb (one of the outputs)
```

Note: I have also tried finding the structure that gives the most substring palidromes, but that way didn't gave me the right results.

Comment: Please provide the start of your code.

Comment: My code is not good. I overshoot my time limit a lot. There should be another way of looking on this task and I was hoping someone could give a hint.

Comment: @Lovren97 still it is a good practice to provide your code

Comment: I am sorry guys, I will put my code.  This is my first time asking anything on Stack.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle The problem is my code is on Croatian because I am from Croatia and I afraid you won't understand a lot of it, or you will need a lot of time to understand everything I wanted to do.

Comment: @Lovren97 Translate it first.

Comment: @user463035818 So the task is to find the permutation of string that contains the most palindromic substrings, also important detail is that the task does have time liimit. If there were no time limit I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: I have a hypothesis: A sorted permutation has most substring palindromes (tied with one or more other permutations). I don't have time to formally prove my hypothesis, but if it is correct, then the task can be solved by sorting the string.

Comment: hm ok sorry for being too picky. I was to focused on "Can anybody help me?" which is kind of a red flag often indicating that there is no specific question just to overlook that your specific question is "How to make it run faster?". removed my last comment. Still we cannot help you with code unless you show us the code ;)

Comment: accccd has (not counting single characters) [cc,cc,cc,ccc,ccc,cccc]. Note that the task didn't ask for unique substrings. (although, even unique substring palindromes are equal at 3)

Comment: @user2079303 arghs yes, I am to stupid to count ;)

Comment: @user2079303 that's actually an interesting idea and it does goes with the theme of my homework which is sorting. I will try it and I will tell if it is correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2079303, unfortunately, it didn't work. But I still think it is an interesting idea and the answer definitely has something to do with sorting the string

Comment: @user2079303 your way actually works! It was just that site on which I was delivering my assignment added some characters when I did my solution in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already answered a similar question before,  [How can we make maximum number of palindromic substrings by rearranging the characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858481/how-can-we-make-maximum-number-of-palindromic-substrings-by-rearranging-the-char/52859794#52859794)

---

The best possible rearrangement of the string which yields the maximum number of palindromes could be that of a `sorted string`. Take, for example, the string `abcabc` and let `n` denote the size of the string in general.

We can rearrange the string to form a palindrome `abc|cba`, which will yield palindromic substrings of length n (all single chars) + n/2 (picking substring across reflection point) + {cases where there exists a palindrome at either of the reflection point, which in this case is 0}.

We can also rearrange the string to form palindromic pairs of the form `(aa)(bb)(cc)`, which will yield n (single chars) + n/2 (pair-wise substring) + {other possible palindromic substrings} palindromes.

Similarly, a 3-pair palindrome can be formed as well `(aba)(cbc)`, in which case the number of palindromes will be n + n/3 + { .. }

Clearly, as we form more m-paired palindrome, the number of palindromic substrings will fall. Hence we need to consider Case I and Case II. Of the two, it is better possible to maximize the {other ..} case for Case II by increasing the density of equal characters appearing together which is the case in a sorted string. Hence, a sorted string should yield an optimal answer.

Hence for your case `oolol` -> `llooo` will given an optimal result of 9 and `gagadbcgghhchbdg` -> `aabbccddfgggghhh` will give the optimal result of 29 as well. You can check for any string using this code: https://ideone.com/mMu2tq

```
def ispalin(s):
    return (s == s[::-1])

def cpalin(s):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            if ispalin(s[i:j + 1]):
                c += 1
    return c

print(cpalin(''.join(sorted("abccbaghghghgdfd"))))
print(cpalin(''.join(sorted("oolol"))))
```